# Rail Installation Error on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm  trying to install Rail on Ubuntu 11.04.
I've installed Ruby1.9.1 and Gem1.3.7. When I typed:

```
gem install rails
```

It returned the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
```

Have you got any ideas?

P.S. I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Is this perhaps related (must specify default encoding)?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650562/invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii-when-trying-to-start-rails-app-with-phusion-pa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved it. I did this error: I installed Ruby with:

```
apt-get install ruby1.9.1
```

And that command isn't the best choice (I don't know motivations).

I followed this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm) to install ruby on Ubuntu, and finaly it works.

Thank for all your solution

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: [When run bundle get invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095845/when-run-bundle-get-invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii), adding this at the top of your Gemfile should fix it:

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end
```

Comment: Sorry where is gemfile located in Ubuntu?

Comment: A Gemfile is located in each Ruby on Rails application; it is not specific to the OS. Therefore, go to the app folder in the application you are creating right now and there you will find the Gemfile

Comment: Sorry but I don't managed to install rails, how can I create a rails app?

Comment: By the type of questions you are making, it seems that you are not very familiar with Ruby on Rails. Why dont you read this tutorial and hopefully things will be clearer: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book