# Rails - rake db:reset rake error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been wrangling with this for hours and can't figure out what is going on. I am trying to run rake db:reset and get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
/Users/zephyr4434/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:16:in `block in trace_on': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
from /Users/zephyr4434/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `map'
from /Users/zephyr4434/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `trace_on'
from /Users/zephyr4434/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:328:in `trace'
from /Users/zephyr4434/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:183:in `display_error_message'
from /Users/zephyr4434/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:169:in `rescue in standard_exception_handling'
from /Users/zephyr4434/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:159:in `standard_exception_handling'
from /Users/zephyr4434/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
from /Users/zephyr4434/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/zephyr4434/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/rake:23:in `load'
from /Users/zephyr4434/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea what is causing this. I tried removing gems I've recently installed but not sure what else I can do.

The rake db:reset seems to work perfectly and then I get this at the end of the console.

Any ideas of what could be causing this?

---

OK I figured it out. I forgot that rake db:reset also runs the seeds.rb file and it turns out that I had some bad data in that file that was causing this issue, so it was not a broader environment issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `#encoding: utf-8` in the first line of your Rakefile

**UPDATE**

Add these lines to the top of Gemfile (solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095845/when-run-bundle-get-invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii))

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end
```

Comment: Thanks - added it to my Gemfile but still getting the error. I ran the bundle command as well but it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Is there a way to trace to the source of the problem?

Comment: Could it be some new gems I've installed recently between commits?

Comment: Well, I have already solved this problem the way I explained above. Another thing you could try in your terminal: export LANG="C.UTF-8" **** and ****
export LC_ALL="C.UTF-8"

Comment: Nothing seems to work for me - I will look into this some more and update when I can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your not typing in your file in romaji (Japanese). 
Or the English character setting for some other non US-ASCII language.